# How to place and order django objects from 2 models into template table?

Tags: django, html-table, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to place "information" into a table that has rows and columns called "categories" and "stylings". My model and view are shown below.

```
model.py

class Headings(models.Model):
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    stylings = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Information(models.Model):
    headings = models.ForeignKey(Headings)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=100)

views.py

class InformationListView(ListView):
    model = Information

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(InformationListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories_ordered'] = Headings.objects.order_by('categories')
        context['stylings_ordered'] = Headings.objects.order_by('stylings')
        return context
```

So far I've been able to start my template table with

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Styles</th>
            {% for cols in categories_ordered %}
                <th class="rotate"><div><span>{{ cols.categories }}</span></div>    
            {% endfor %}
        </th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in stylings_ordered %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.stylings }}</td>
            {% for col in categories_ordered %}
                <td>
                    ... need algorithm  that places the correct info in this cell. {{ Information.info }}
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

There could be 6 different categories and 6 different stylings, but maybe only 4 information objects.  So the hard part (imo) is placing the information in the correct cell in the table. I've tried different things but nothing that seems to be close. I imagine this is a fairly common problem that is solved all the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
headings = models.ForeignKey(Headings)
```

attribute headings of Information is FK of Headings.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Styles</th>
            {% for cols in categories_ordered %}
                <th class="rotate"><div><span>{{ cols.categories }}</span></div>    
            {% endfor %}
        </th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in stylings_ordered %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.stylings }}</td>
            {% for col in row.information_set.all() %}
                <td>col.info</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

[You can check many to one relationship in Django manual in detail.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

---

answer for a comment

Do you mean this?
[image]

```
class Styles(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    info = JSONField(default={})

class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    styles = models.ForeignKey(Styles)
```

I would use JSONField. If you use PostgresSQL, You can use JSONField in DJango. [JSON Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield)

```
#views.py
class PlayGround(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        categories = Categories.objects.all()
        styles = Styles.objects.all()
        return render(
                       request,
                       'playground.html',
                       {"categories": categories, "styles": styles}
        )

# adding template filter to get value from key in template
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key, '')
```

I don't know that it is best way but this is what I could come up with.

```
# playground.html
    <table >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Styles</th>
                {% for category in categories %}
                <th>{{category.name}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            {% for style in styles %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{style.name}}</td>
                {% for category in categories %}
                <td>{{style.info|get_item:category.name}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

styles sample data

```
id 1
name "teststyle"
info "{"skiing": "info2", "painting": "info1"}"
```

[image]

Comment: Yes but that just places info into the table from left to right all in one row.  The info won't necessarily line up with the headings.  Suppose categories are entered in this order: sports, hobbies, painting, pottery, photography, skiing.  Suppose there is only one stylings.  Then perhaps there are only two info entered, one for painting and one for skiing.  The table should skip the first two columns, fill in painting, skip the pottery and photography columns, and then fill in the skiing column.  It gets even more complicated when both the row and column have to be matched up.

Comment: check my answer please

Comment: Yes, that looks like what I am trying to do.